# Getting time span between two times in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have two textboxes. One for a clock in time and one for clock out. The times will be put in this format:

```
Hours:Minutes
```

Lets say I have clocked in at 7:00 AM and clocked out at 2:00 PM.

With my current code, I get a difference of 2 hours, but it should be 7 hours. How would I do that in C#. I was going to convert to the 24 hour, by letting the user select AM or PM, but I got confused.

So, basically, how would I calculate the difference of hours between the two times?

I tried this, but got 2 hours and not 7 when I plugged in the numbers.

```
DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
DateTime endtime = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox2.Text);

TimeSpan duration = startTime - endtime;
```

Comment: What is the exact content of your text boxes?

Comment: You're checking that the times have parsed correctly?  That is, you've verified the values of `startTime` and `endTime`?

Comment: well users are supposed to put in ... 7:00 (any time) into the textboxes

Comment: I don't understand how you know whether "2:00" is AM or PM. Also, what culture do you use (which locale)? Btw it should be `duration = end - start`, not the other way around

Comment: Using "7:00" ; "7:00am" ; "7:00 am" ; "7:00AM" ; "7:00 AM" all work just fine. I'm curious to see exactly what textBox1.Text is since I cannot duplicate your issue.

Comment: is there any chance that one of your text boxes is by default set to "00:00" and that you either use the wrong one in the code, or somehowe overwrite the value (e.g. during validation)? This would explain `02:00 - 00:00 => 2 h`

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
string startTime = "7:00 AM";
string endTime = "2:00 PM";

TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(endTime).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(startTime));

Console.WriteLine(duration);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Will output: 07:00:00.

It also works if the user input military time:

```
string startTime = "7:00";
string endTime = "14:00";

TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(endTime).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(startTime));

Console.WriteLine(duration);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Outputs: 07:00:00.

*To change the format:* `duration.ToString(@"hh\:mm")`

*More info at:* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx

**Addendum:**

Over the years it has somewhat bothered me that this is the most popular answer I have ever given; the original answer never actually explained why the OP's code didn't work despite the fact that it *is* perfectly valid. The only reason it gets so many votes is because the post comes up on Google when people search for a combination of the terms "C#", "timespan", and "between".

Comment: `TimeSpan duration = endtime - startTime;` works too in this example.

Comment: @EliteGamer See this documentation on [time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

Comment: @EliteGamer, how does this answer your question?

Comment: It still doesn't explain how the result was 2 hours as the code is essentially the same as his (with changed order of endTime and startTime)

Comment: It's not working with following case string startTime = "8:00 PM";
string endTime = "12:00 PM";

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif What would you expect as a result? The time value of 12:00 (12:00 PM) is indeed eight hours behind the time value of 20:00 (8:00 PM)...

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif Nevermind, I suppose he just messed something up while testing to end up with that kind of bogus result. There are other explanations involving time zones that -might- explain but I've never been one to speculate about such things...

Answer (score 19):

You could use the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zz841zbz.aspx) constructor which takes a long for Ticks:

```
 TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(endtime.Ticks - startTime.Ticks);
```

Answer (score 4):

Two points:

1. Check your inputs. I can't imagine a situation where you'd get 2 hours by subtracting the time values you're talking about. If I do this:

   ```
       DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime("7:00 AM");
       DateTime endtime = Convert.ToDateTime("2:00 PM");
       TimeSpan duration = startTime - endtime;
   ```

   ... I get `-07:00:00` as the result. And even if I forget to provide the AM/PM value:

   ```
       DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime("7:00");
       DateTime endtime = Convert.ToDateTime("2:00");
       TimeSpan duration = startTime - endtime;
   ```

   ... I get `05:00:00`. So either your inputs don't contain the values you have listed or you are in a machine environment where they are begin parsed in an unexpected way. Or you're not actually getting the results you are reporting.
2. To find the difference between a start and end time, you need to do `endTime - startTime`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

If i rotate trough sorted list of times (like schedule list) at some point i need to get interval between last and first times , and so far i come to this solution:

```
  TimeSpan t1 = TimeSpan.Parse("23:00");
  TimeSpan t2 = TimeSpan.Parse("3:10");
  double _24h = (new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0)).TotalMilliseconds;
  double diff = t2.TotalMilliseconds - t1.TotalMilliseconds;
  if (diff < 0) diff += _24h;
  Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(diff)); // output: 04:10:00
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another way ( longer ) In VB.net  [ Say 2300 Start and  0700 Finish next day ]

If tsStart > tsFinish Then

```
                            ' Take Hours difference and adjust accordingly
                            tsDifference = New TimeSpan((24 - tsStart.Hours) + tsFinish.Hours, 0, 0)

                            ' Add Minutes to Difference
                            tsDifference = tsDifference.Add(New TimeSpan(0, Math.Abs(tsStart.Minutes - tsFinish.Minutes), 0))


                            ' Add Seonds to Difference
                            tsDifference = tsDifference.Add(New TimeSpan(0, 0, Math.Abs(tsStart.Seconds - tsFinish.Seconds)))
```

Answer (score 0):

With .NET Core 6 consider [TimeOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly?view=net-6.0)

.NET Fiddle [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R3MF2G)

```
using System;                       
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        TimeOnly endTime = new(14, 0, 0);
        TimeOnly startTime = new(7, 0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine((endTime - startTime).ToString(@"hh\:mm"));
        Console.WriteLine((endTime - startTime));
    }
}
```

We get `07:00` and `07:00:00`