# How to find difference between 2 time strings in HHMMSSmmmuuu format in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have two time strings in `HH:MM:SS:mmm:uuu` format. How to find the difference (time span) between them?

```
string t1="06:37:30:210:111";
string t2="06:38:32:310:222";
```

I want to find the difference (in terms of time) between `t2` and `t1` (`t2-t1`).

How to do this?

Comment: Did you actually try to solve the problem? Do you have a specific question about your code?

Comment: Have you tried to use `DateTime.Parse`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521366/getting-time-span-between-two-times-in-c

Comment: What is `uuu` in your string format?

Comment: mmm is Milli seconds and uuu is micro seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string t1 = "06:37:30:210:111";
        string t2 = "06:38:32:310:222";

        var tp1 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(
            t1.Remove(t1.LastIndexOf(":")),
            @"hh\:mm\:ss\:FFFFFF",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        var tp2 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(
            t2.Remove(t2.LastIndexOf(":")),
            @"hh\:mm\:ss\:FFFFFF",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        Console.WriteLine(tp2 - tp1);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: This example actually works for the specific data in the question so gets my vote.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your strings to DateTime and use TimeSpan to calculate the difference

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse(t1);
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse(t2);
TimeSpan ts = d2.Subtract(d1);
```

Comment: No need for Subtract() call. `d2-d1` would suffice and is more readable as the '-' operator results in a TimeSpan as well (it uses Subtract behind the scenes)

Comment: Are you sure `"06:37:30:210:111"` will be recognized as datetime?

Comment: I tried this. But i am getting this error : **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**