# Get End Time from Start Time and Duration

Tags: c#

I have start time in format hh:mm:ss and then entering duration in hours and selecting a day of week.

I want to calculate the end time based on above parameters.

For Example: of start time is 00:00:00 and duartion entered is 48 hours with day of week as Sunday. The end time must be 00:00:00 hrs on Tuesday.

How to do it?

Comment: Please read this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521366/getting-time-span-between-two-times-in-c

Hope it help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
//assuming that you have a validation for your startTime that this will always on this format "HH:mm:ss"
private static string GetEndTime(string startTime, int duration, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.Parse(startTime);
    DateTime endDateTime = startDateTime.AddHours(duration);

    return endDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}

private static DayOfWeek GetEndDay(int duration, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    int days = duration / 24;
    DayOfWeek endDay = dayOfWeek + days;

    return endDay;
}

static void Main()
{
    string testStartTime = "00:00:00";
    DayOfWeek startDay = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
    int duration = 48;

    string endTime = GetEndTime(testStartTime, duration, startDay);
    DayOfWeek endDay = GetEndDay(duration, startDay);
    Console.WriteLine("End Time is {0} hours on {1}", endTime, endDay.ToString());

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void Main()
{
    var today = "Sunday";
    DayOfWeek dw;
    DayOfWeek.TryParse(today, true, out dw);
    int hours = 48;
    int days = hours / 24;
    int remainder = hours % 24;
    DayOfWeek endDay = dw + days;
    Console.Write("End time: {0} at {1}", endDay, remainder);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind due to leaps/DST/etc., adding 48 hours won't always result in exactly two `DayOfWeek`s passing keeping the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [DateTime.AddHours()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours.aspx) function

Answer (score 1):

Add a TimeSpan to a DateTime :

```
var today = System.DateTime.Now;
var duration = new System.TimeSpan(48, 0, 0, 0);
var endDateTime= today.Add(duration);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string start = "00:00:00";
DayOfWeek startDay = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
int duration = 48;
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(start);
while(date.DayOfWeek != startDay)
{
    date = date.AddDays(1);
}
date = date.AddHours(duration);

DayOfWeek resultDay = date.DayOfWeek;
string time = date.ToLongTimeString();
```